# How to go to the already opened window based on the URL using webdriver API

Tags: c#, selenium, webdriver

```
private  static IEWebbrowser GetGrid1()
{
   foreach (var m in new ShellWindows().Cast<IEWebbrowser >().Where(m => m.Url.Length > 22 && m.Url.Substring(0, 23) == "https://grid.sample.com"))
            return m;
   throw new Exception("please open the Grid website prior to pressing the button");        
}
```

I have the above code which is to be re-wrtten using webdrvier API. I cannot use shellwindows() in selenium webdriver. I have an exception trying with below code. could anyone please suggest me.

```
private  static IWebDriver GetGrid1()
{     
     foreach (var m in new ShellWindows().Cast<IWebDriver>().Where(m => m.Url.Length > 22 && m.Url.Substring(0, 23) == "https://grid.sample.com"))
            return m;
     throw new Exception("WebDriver:Please open the Grid website prior to pressing the button");       
 }
```

It builds success but going to exception during runtime.

Comment: Please show the exception you are getting.

Comment: How its related to Selenium?